# Java void into an int array

Tags: java

how do I store a void in to an array?

for my example:
count (String text) into int[] letter.

is there a quick and easy opportunity to do it or should I rewrite it completely?

I really appreciate your help

my code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    String text="E";

    String[] words = split(text);
    int[] letter = count(text);
    someWords(words, letter);
}   

public static int[] count(String text){
    int count;

    for (char letter=(char)65;letter<=90;letter++){
        count=0;

        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){

            if (letter==text.charAt(I) || (letter+32)==text.charAt(I)){
            count++;
            }


        } 
            if (count>0){
            System.out.println(letter+" = "+count);
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: change the return type to `int[]`. But i have no clue why you would want to store the count variable, which is a single int, into an int array.

Comment: By definition, you can't store void (it won't even compile). You must edit your count method to return the count.

Comment: @KevinEsche i already did it :) but i dont have any clue why eclipse wont let me just return count :/

Comment: @manonmars because your method must be declared to return an `int`. `public static int count(String text)` in order to return count. To store the result in an array doesn´t look right either here.

Comment: The question "how do I store a void ...?" is meaningless. `void` is not a type, when a method is `void` it means it does not return a value. There's nothing to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you want to do it like this, but you can just pass the `int[]` as a paramter.

```
...
int[] count = new int[1];
count(text, count);
...

public static void count(String text, int[] count){
   ...
   count[0] = ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, because your question is not very clear, but it seems that what you're trying to do is:

```
public static int[] count(String text){
    int[] counts = new int[26];

    // iterate over each letter:
    for (char letter='A';letter<='Z';letter++){
        int currentIndex = (int) letter - 'A';

        // count the occurrences of the current letter:
        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){
            if (letter==text.charAt(i) || (letter+32)==text.charAt(i)){
                counts[currentIndex]++;
            }
        } 
        // print the count for the current letter if non-zero
        if (counts[currentIndex]>0){
            System.out.println(letter+" = " + counts[currentIndex]);
        }
    }
    return counts;
}
```

There's surely a more efficient way to do this (iterating over the characters in `text` and incrementing the count index accordingly would be faster than checking all the chars in `text` 26 times), but the approach works.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code it seems like you just want to return and integer and not an integer array (the number of letters in a String as it seems)

```
public static int count(String text){
    int count;

    for (char letter=(char)65;letter<=90;letter++){
        count=0;     // are you sure you want to set the value of count to 0 every time you loop?
        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){

            if (letter==text.charAt(i) || (letter+32)==text.charAt(i)){
            count++;
            }
        } 
        if (count>0){
            System.out.println(letter+" = "+count);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

In your main method you write:

```
String[] words = split(text);
int letter = count(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int count()
{
count = 0;
for ...
...
...
return count;
}
```

you should use RETURN word at the end of your function, and declare the return type (int, string, ...etc) next to the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to spin through the string once:

```
public static int[] count(String text) {
    int[] totals = new int[26];
    for (char c : text.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        int idx = (int)c - (int)'A';
        if ((idx >= 0) && (idx <= 26)) {
           totals[idx]++; 
        }
    }
    return totals;
}
```

Comment: @manonmars Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.